# Unlogical C6001 warning: Using uninitialized memory warning in C with Visual Studio

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

Given this code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *p;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct Test()
{
    MyStruct ms;
    ms.p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    if (!ms.p) exit(-1);
    return ms;
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        MyStruct t = Test();
        free(t.p); // C6001: Using uninitialized memory 't.p'.
    }
}
```

Visual Studio shows C6001 warning on the `free` call line. However, I see there is no way to achieve the free line with the memory t.p uninitialized. What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: I am using MSVC compiled from a console (not with Visual Studio) and I get no compiler warnings. I set a value in each of the 5 locations, in the function, and printed them in `main`. When I ran it, it is correct but does not stop.

Comment: @WeatherVane, In my real application, I wait for some user inputs and stuff like that, and the loop is desired there. But the real code is too long, I tried to simplify the code as possible.

Comment: Does the example posted give a compiler warning?

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yup. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Did you try to return addresses and to use a pointer to struct? This definitely looks like poor prediction of compiler.

Comment: @Northsoft the `struct` goes out of life when the function ends.

Comment: @Northsoft, I don't want to bother myself with allocating dynamic memory for the struct itself. So, this a false positive warning ?
I can just ignore it if I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: Pasting OP's *exact* code into MSCV and running "Code Analysis" gives the said C6001 warning - working on why!

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica of course, returning an actual `struct` is perfectly valid, so long as any member pointers don't point to local variables (they don't).

Comment: A `struct` is returned by value, unless explicitly returning a pointer.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica, Yes. That will remove the warning, but I really don't want to make that change in my code base.

Comment: This is going off at a tangent. The "return a pointer to `struct`" will only work when a) you passed a pointer to a valid `struct` as an argument, or b) you allocated memory for the `struct` in the function.

Comment: Yes - The comment by @Northsoft sums it up: poor code analysis!

Comment: Well, Then I'm going to simply ignore that warning. Thanks for the help ^_^.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very much a false positive and still exists even in MSVC 2019. There is no way that the `t.p` variable could be uninitialised.

In fact, there is no way it could reach the `free()` statement without it being initialised to a *non-NULL* value. But, even if you allow for the possibility the compiler doesn't know that the `exit()` function won't return, that's actually irrelevant, Whether it returns or not, the structure would still be initialised to *something* and, in any case, it's perfectly legal to `free(NULL)`.

Removing the `if .. exit` has no effect on the warning so I doubt that's the issue. It's more likely that this is just MSVC being aggressive in reporting warnings and the best way to stop it from bothering you is to simply ignore it.

By that, I don't mean *you* ignoring the warning (I could never do that given my nature), I mean telling MSVC to shut up about it:

```c
while (1) {
    MyStruct t = Test();

    // MSVC wrongly reports this as using uninitialised variable.
    #pragma warning(push)
    #pragma warning(disable: 6001)
    free(t.p);
    #pragma warning(pop)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

1. sometimes SAL warnings can be "treated" by having malloc() replaced by calloc()

a) much more precise (element size *and* count params provided) - better analyzer prediction?

b) different API - that one possibly not instrumented, thus no analyzer output? ;-P

2. analysis might be confused via the exit() within that function, which smells a bit like being related to [missing] noreturn attribution (this case very similar to bailing out of a return-value-based function via exception throw), see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes ; OTOH the noreturn attribution thing is *conditional* here (i.e., not in all code paths), thus a noreturn attribution smells imprecise/wrong (the code *is* trying to use a function result after all)
3. generally, try to aggressively "break" things into achieving "working" warning-free behaviour, by progressively removing (potentially larger) pieces of the implementation until it starts to "work". E.g. in this case, removing the exit() line may cause changed SAL behaviour and thus provide clues as to what aspect actually is the "problem".
4. perhaps the design might be less optimal than possible - in such cases, possibly some limited rework might lead to more "obvious"/"elegant"/"modern" handling which may result in not producing such SAL warnings.